# What can I do with "Could not parse configuration" error from Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, parsing, configuration

I am following [Java Hibernate tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GINvxAaXDbY&feature=related) example from YouTube. Everything looks great until I try to run code which is supposed to create table Employee on Apache Derby server. I tried to use SQL server (2008) first and I was getting the same error.
**Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml** and there is also **timeout error**. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

**Here is the error I get:**

```
17:28:51,574  INFO Version:15 - Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA
17:28:51,587  INFO Environment:560 - Hibernate 3.3.2.GA
17:28:51,590  INFO Environment:593 - hibernate.properties not found
17:28:51,594  INFO Environment:771 - Bytecode provider name : javassist
17:28:51,597  INFO Environment:652 - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
17:28:51,648  INFO Version:14 - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.1.0.GA
17:28:51,655  INFO Configuration:1474 - configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
17:28:51,655  INFO Configuration:1451 - Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
17:28:51,702 DEBUG DTDEntityResolver:64 - trying to resolve system-id [http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd]
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1542)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1035)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1476)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1017)
    at com.hibernate.chapter1.TestEmployee.main(TestEmployee.java:14)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection timed out: connect Nested exception: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1532)
    ... 5 more
```

**Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/HibernateDb;create=true</property>
        <property name="connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**And, here is the code I am running:**

```
package com.hibernate.chapter1;   
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;
public class TestEmployee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class);
        config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);
    }    
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means the hibernate.dtd cannot be resolved - its resolution is attempted on the server. The dtd is contained in the jars files - see [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=949031) and [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?80886-How-to-configure-hibernate.cfg.xml-to-work-offline) for how to resolve it.

Comment: Thank you for your time to respond. I have looked in my hibernater3.jar and there is the file named "hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" which is exactly how it is mentioned in declaration in hibernate.cfg.xml. Looking at other posts I noticed that the path I used is different. My path was: http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ While other people used: http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/ . I changed the path and now everything works. The thing is, I think it is still being pulled from internet instead from my hibernate3.jar. Is there a way to force it to be loaded from local resources. Thanks.

Comment: your dtd isn't getting pulled from the internet.. the uri of the dtd that you specify should match uri mentioned in the dtd present inside your jar. It looks like and opens into a website but it isnt pulled from there..