# MappingNotFoundException: resource: user.hbm.xml not found

Tags: java, hibernate

[image]Hi i am tying to make simple web application for user registration form using jsp and hibernate When i run my application  i  am getting following Exeption

```
MappingNotFoundException: resource: user.hbm.xml not found
```

Here is My code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools.                   -->
**hibernate.cfg.xml**
    <hibernate-configuration>

          <session-factory>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee</property>
            <property name="connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="connection.password"></property>
            <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="hiber/user.hbm.xml"/>
        </session-factory>

    </hibernate-configuration>
```

**user.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

          <hibernate-mapping>
          <class name="User" table="u400">
          <id name="id">
          <generator class="increment"></generator>
          </id>
          <property name="name"></property>
          <property name="password"></property>
          <property name="email"></property>
          </class>
          </hibernate-mapping>
```

project Structure is as following

```
 Project
    |
    |-WebPages
    |
    |-src
    |-hiber
    |  |-user.java
       |-UserDao.java
       |-user.hbm.xml
       |-hibernate.cfg.xml
```

How can i remove this Exception and what should i do

Thanks in advance
getting following Exception

```
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hiber/hibernate.cfg.xml

root cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hiber/hibernate.cfg.xml

root cause

org.dom4j.DocumentException: hibernate.sourceforge.net Nested exception: hibernate.sourceforge.net
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the jar version of hibernate and compare it with DTD version inside `hibernate.cfg.xml`

it should match basically otherwise it can not resolve the dependencies.

Comment: i am using hibernet 3.0  jar and dtd version in file is 3.0

Comment: okie..then try to remove encoding='UTF-8' from hibernate.cfg.cml

Answer (score 3):

Silly mistake:-
your pojo/persistent class has "User.java" name which begins with capital 'U' but the mapping file "user.hbm.xml" begins with small 'u'.
Solution:- both names should be same. eg:- "User.java" and "User.hbm.xml".
-- Happy Coding.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Maven, put your `hbm.xml` file into resource folder under:

`/resource/[your package]/hbm.xml`

Comment: WORK!!! just move the [hibernate_file_class_name].hbm.xml to resources directory and re-check hibernate.cfg.xml then it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to give full path for your user.hbm.xml in hibernate.cfg.xml.

```
<mapping resource="hiber/user.hbm.xml"/>
```

Comment: i added full path   in my post

Comment: Your hbm file is inside hiber folder according to your project structure.

Comment: i did this now i am getting other exeption

Comment: i have updated in my post  which Exception i am getting

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183252/what-can-i-do-with-could-not-parse-configuration-error-from-hibernate)

Answer (score -2):

Don't use full path in mapping resource :

```
<mapping resource="user.hbm.xml"/>
```

instead of

```
<mapping resource="hiber/user.hbm.xml"/>
```

Its work for me hopefully for you.