# hibernate.cfg.xml error creation

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I'm using eclipse kepler to start a dynamic web project with hibernate and mysql. I've installed all plugins and I added all libs needed . And when I want to create a configuration file. I've configured the connection and I've tested it and the Ping succeeds. but the problem is that can't generate classes from my database.
So I can't do a hibernate mapping. 
this is the error :

```
[Classpath]: Could not parse configuration:E:\test\src\hibernate.cfg.xml
```

Comment: Please send you `hibernate.cfg.xml` and full stack trace.

Comment: There is no stack trace because i'm trying to create the config file from console configuration

Comment: Can you post your config file ?

Comment: seems like the parser is not able to parse the version of the hibernate.cfg.xml that yoiu have. PLease check the DOCTYPE tag at the top of your xml file. may be you may have to tweak it a bit

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

Comment: Check the jar version of hibernate and compare it with DTD version inside hibernate.cfg.xml
 [Check This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605638/mappingnotfoundexception-resource-user-hbm-xml-not-found/23605899#23605899)